# How to edit an item in the treeview in wpf

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0, treeviewitem

My `TreeView` `ItemTemplate` looks like below.

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Connections}">
        <WrapPanel >
            <CheckBox  VerticalAlignment="Center" Command="{Binding UpdateConnections}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" IsChecked="{Binding Status,  Mode=TwoWay}" Focusable="False"  Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TreeView_CheckBox_Style}"></CheckBox>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"  Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=treeTextBoxStyle}"  />
         </WrapPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

I am using MVVM. I would like to edit the `TextBox` if my tree item starts with "s".

I basically double click my `TreeViewItem` and I should be able to type in it.

How do i do it ?

Comment: I can see the `TextBlock` there but not any `TextBox`.

Comment: Ok. I want to edit tat textBlock. How do i do it.

Comment: `TextBlock` is read only. You better use a `TextBox` and manipulate its `IsReadOnly` property.